# How to pass variable name from a file and use that variable in script in unix

Tags: shell, variables, unix, scripting

I have a config file in unix as

```
Variable_name:sequences:Status
ABC:1234:/path/txt

and I have a script in unix as

$ABC="select * from table"
```

I want to pass the variable name from file and use the variable in script with the value in script.

so I need to run script like

```
for i in /path/file_config;
 $Variable=ABC
 echo $variable # need result "select* from table"
```

Please help me in this

Comment: `$ABC=` and `$Variable=` are invalid. That's not how you assign to variables.

Comment: The answers given are different from how I understand your question. I think you have one variable name in the config file, and you want that string for selecting the SQL statement in the script. Something like `var=ABC; grep "^\$${var}=" /path/config | cut -d '"' -f2 `. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` (But not other shells), `${!foo}` is an indirect reference that expands to the value of the variable named in `$foo`.

So,

```
ABC="select * from table"
name=ABC
echo "${!name}"
```

will display `select * from table`

Comment: Please put the sql in single quotes, I don't want `*` replaces by filenames. (off-topic: I understand the question differently)

Comment: @WalterA Why would it get replaced with double quotes?

Comment: Sorry, my `echo ${ABC}` was wrong. I should have done `echo "${ABC}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slight improvement to Shawn's response above:

```
for Variable_name in `awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /path/file_config`; do
Variable=$Variable_name
echo ${!Variable}
done
```